# Is it possible to inspect `GM_xmlhttpRequest`s in the Developer Tools network tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, tampermonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I found out that you can perform a CORS request within a Tampermonkey script using `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`.  Unfortunately, they don't appear in the Chrome devtools network tab.

I know GM_ functions are running in their own scope somewhere within the extension.

Is there a way to inspect such requests?

Comment: See [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029) - the request is shown there.

Comment: nice ^^. Many thanks!